# I added to manifest, but android permission but it is missing

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

I added permissions to AndroidManifest.xml and I check it is upper than <application
but when I build it to AVD, It doesn't have permissions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gioom">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

there is only storage permission

[pic of AVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GINm.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In newer android versions you must request certain permissions from the user at runtime in addition to declaring them in the Manifest.

See the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for more info

Hope this helps.

Comment: ```WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORATE``` was just test. I added ```INTERNET``` and ```WIFI_STATE``` request in kt, but there is only storage... It is so strange. I can't understand why is it. I check spelling too!

Comment: Some permissions does not require asking the user such as INTERNET.
However, when your app requires a special permission (such as LOCATION, STORAGE etc.) you have to ask the user at runtime - this started at android 6 (API 23).

Comment: Oh... Tkx It is help to me T0T